# Python String formatting for datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime, formatting

I am trying to solve a problem:

In the library code I have something like:

```
return format % (value.year, value.month, value.day, value.hour, 
                 value.minute,value.second, value.microsecond)
```

where format is a string with formatting:

```
format = "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%06d"
```

For this format possible output can be:

```
2015-02-26 11:28:45.466000
```

I can only set up format (string format, maybe some function?), library code is untouchable. Is there any way to receive something like:

```
2015-02-26 11:28:45
```

Comment: `string.split('.')[0]`

Comment: What library? Why is it untouchable? Do you have more context to offer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just datetime

Comment: Maybe I did not explain it enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have several amongst which:

- Split the string and use it, which is great for a one-shot
- Parsing the date back, which might be better if you are doing other operations on it

Here are these options with examples :

---

You can use the function [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to do this and use the character `.` as delimiter.
Note that this assumes that you will ever only get one point in your string.

```
result = "2015-02-26 11:28:45.466000" 
final_str = result.split('.')[0]
print(final_str)
>>> 2015-02-26 11:28:45
```

---

Parsing the date back with [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) :

```
import datetime

date_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
result_str = "2015-02-26 11:28:45.466000"

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(result_str, date_fmt+".%f")
date_str = date.strftime(date_fmt)

print(date_str)
>>> 2015-02-26 11:28:45
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` function

```
def reduce(mydate):
     newformat = mydate.split('.')[0]
     return newformat

print(reduce("2015-02-26 11:28:45.466000")) #2015-02-26 11:28:45
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: It's "better" to have `#` for comments in python! :)